# Make file not working?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, makefile, executable

Solution found. See below:

I'm trying to get my makefile to compile three c programs into one executable, but I get the following error:

```
cachesim.o: could not read symbols: File in wrong format
```

Yes, I'm using make clean every time I use it. The make file is as follow

```
CC     = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -m32 -O -g

all:  cachesim cache trace_file_parser 
gcc -o cachesim cachesim.o cache.o trace_file_parser.o

cachesim:       cachesim.c
        $(CC) -c -o cachesim.o cachesim.c $(CFLAGS)

cache:          cache.c
        $(CC) -c -o cache.o cache.c $(CFLAGS)

trace_file_parser:  trace_file_parser.c
        $(CC) -c -o trace_file_parser.o trace_file_parser.c $(CFLAGS)

clean:
rm -f *.o
```

I cannot figure out why this is....

I'm using make clean every time.

Attempting to compile:

```
[katiea@mumble-15] (34)$ make clean
rm -f *.o
[katiea@mumble-15] (35)$ ls
cache.c   cache.h     cachesim.c~      gcc_trace  Makefile~     trace_file_parser.c
cache.c~  cachesim.c  cache_structs.h  Makefile   strgen_trace  trace_file_parser.h
[katiea@mumble-15] (36)$ make
gcc -c -o cachesim.o cachesim.c -Wall -m32 -O -g
gcc -c -o cache.o cache.c -Wall -m32 -O -g
gcc -c -o trace_file_parser.o trace_file_parser.c -Wall -m32 -O -g
gcc -o cachesim cachesim.o cache.o trace_file_parser.o
cachesim.o: could not read symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

SOLUTION

```
CC     = gcc

CFLAGS = -Wall -m32 -O -g

all:  cachesim.c cache.c trace_file_parser.c
$(CC) -o cachesim cachesim.c cache.c trace_file_parser.c $(CFLAGS)

cachesim:       cachesim.c
        $(CC) -c -o cachesim.o cachesim.c $(CFLAGS)

cache:          cache.c
        $(CC) -c -o cache.o cache.c $(CFLAGS)

trace_file_parser:  trace_file_parser.c
        $(CC) -c -o trace_file_parser.o trace_file_parser.c $(CFLAGS)

clean:
rm -f *.o
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please read an intro to makefiles.  This looks like homework to me.

One of the most basic tenets of makefiles is that the target should be the actual file you're building.  These rules are all bogus:

```
cachesim:       cachesim.c
         $(CC) -c -o cachesim.o cachesim.c $(CFLAGS)
```

(etc.) because the target is `cachesim` but the recipe (command line) builds the file `cachesim.o`.

Your makefile can be written as easily as this (taking advantage of make's built-in rules):

```
CC      = gcc
CFLAGS  = -Wall -m32 -O -g
LDFLAGS = -m32 -O -g

cachesim: cachesim.o cache.o trace_file_parser.o

clean:
        rm -f *.o
```

That's all you need.

As for your error, it seems to me that the file `cachesim.o` must be in some bizarre format, maybe from back before you had the makefile set up properly.

If you run `make clean` then `make` again, do you get the same error?  If so please show the compile and link lines.

ETA: use the `-m32` flag on the link line as well as the compile line, if you want to create a 32bit program.

Comment: I'm using make clean every time. 

Attempting to compile:

Comment: Oh.  You're compiling the object files as 32bit, with the `-m32` flag, but you aren't putting `-m32` on the link line so it's trying to link the program as a 64bit program and thus the 32bit `.o` files have the wrong format.

Comment: So like thus:

    all:  cachesim.c cache.c trace_file_parser.c
 $(CC) -o cachesim cachesim.c cache.c trace_file_parser.c $(CFLAGS)

Comment: I've updated my answer.  Your original makefile is just not right, for the reasons I stated earlier.

Comment: And the gap in my understanding was the -m32 flag. After I understood that, I was able to complete a working MakeFile. 

I've used Makefiles in the past, but never received the error I mentioned above until today. Thank you for helping me parse the meaning.

Comment: If you're happy with it, that's fine.  However your makefile is still all wrong; it shows a fundamental misunderstanding of make and makefiles.  Most of this makefile is not even used.  In fact, as you've written it above it's useless to even create a makefile.  You'd get exactly the same behavior by creating a shell script and putting the link line in it, then just running that script whenever you wanted to rebuild the code.

Comment: You're completely correct, and I agree - but you're right, I'm creating this makefile for a course, which simply *only* wanted me to add the CFLAGS and All section. Between the two, I didn't know if it was appropriate to make them link in all, as I usually add a Link target.